# jQuery mousenter works on table data but not whole table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, hover, mouseenter

I have a table built as follows:

```
  <table id="my_table">
     <tbody>
         <tr class="row"><th>No</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Salary</th></tr>
         <tr class="row"><td>1</td><td>Yong Mook Kim</td><td>28</td><td>$100,000</td></tr>
         <tr class="row"><td>2</td><td>Low Yin Fong</td><td>29</td><td>$90,000</td></tr>
         <tr class="row"><td>3</td><td>Ah Pig</td><td>18</td><td>$50,000</td></tr>
         <tr class="row"><td>4</td><td>Ah Dog</td><td>28</td><td>$40,000</td></tr>
         <tr class="row"><td>5</td><td>Ah Cat</td><td>28</td><td>$30,000</td></tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

And I would like to do some simple effects on the whole row the cursor is currently on. Sadly the events only fire when the cursor enters in a table data area. Here's my Jquery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#my_table").on("mouseenter", ".row", handle_zooming_in);
});

function handle_zooming_in() {  
        $("#pool").append("<img class=\"popup\" src="+image_url+">");
        $(".popup").css({"position":"absolute","left":event.pageX,"top":event.pageY}).show();
}
```

To be more clear, the handle_zooming_in function only fires when the cursor is on a word that's inside a  tag. I should probably also point out that the table is empty when the page is initially opened and rows are added in a second time via javascript. Am I missing something?

Comment: that is not **.row** u should use **row**

Comment: @Kermani, `.row` is correct, because it's a class.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Oh yes, I thought he is using that to call a tr.

Comment: I make a simple test on local replacing the logic inside of `handle_zooming_in` with a `console.log` and add some rows via js. `console.log` works as expected. I don't see a problem, are you sure that you are not getting an error message?

Comment: seems to be working in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqzz5aw6/2/)

Comment: Yep, frikinside. No error messages are shown.

Comment: I make a jsFiddle with an interval adding rows and a console.log and gets fired just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/bv7zzcy1/1/

Comment: Updates: the problem only shows on chrome, on IE it's just perfect. Also, if I change the position of the <tr> from "static" to "absolute" the event fires as it should (also in spaces between <td>). But absolute positioning destroys my layout ofc.

Comment: I test this in chrome without any trouble. The jsFiddle provide by @EdanFeiles and the jsFiddle that I put on my previous comment. Did you check both of them?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my_table").on("mouseenter", ".row", handle_zooming_in);
});

function handle_zooming_in() {
  if($('td',this)>0){
 console.log("NOT EMPTY");
  $("#pool").append("<img class=\"popup\" src="+image_url+">");
   $(".popup").css({"position":"absolute","left":event.pageX,"top":event.pageY}).show();
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Yong Mook Kim</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>$100,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Low Yin Fong</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>$90,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Ah Pig</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>$50,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Ah Dog</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>$40,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Ah Cat</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>$30,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
And I would like to do some simple effects on the whole row the cursor is currently on. Sadly the events only fire when the cursor enters in a table data area. Here's my Jquery code:
```

try this may it helps

Answer (score 0):

Declare `$("#my_table").on("mouseenter", ".row", handle_zooming_in);` after the rows are added with javascript.

And maybe change that code to `$('.row').on("mouseenter", handle_zooming_in);` ?

Comment: Using `on` should avoid the need of having the elements loaded in DOM menawhile `#my_table"` exists.

Comment: Yes, that was the reason.

Comment: @frikinside, that's not true.  According to http://api.jquery.com/on/, "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()."

Comment: @RickHitchcock maybe you should read the previous two paragraphs. The element that needs to exist in this case is `#my_table` especifying a selector as params means that the event is attached as delegated and not as direct. Using this answer as example: `$("#my_table").on("mouseenter", ".row", handle_zooming_in);` is an event attached as delegate, `#my_table` needs to exist, `.row` dont. But `$('.row').on("mouseenter", handle_zooming_in);` is an event attached as direct so `.row` must exist.

Comment: @frikinside, you're absolutely correct, and I should have caught that.  Apologies!